# Finding number of concurrent events given start and end times

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, computational-geometry

I have a massive (~10<sup>9</sup>) set of events characterized by a start and end time. Given a time, I want to find how many on those events were ongoing at that time.

What sort of data structure would be helpful in this situation? The operations I need to be fast are:

1. Inserting new events, e.g., `{start: 100000 milliseconds, end: 100010 milliseconds}`.
2. Querying the number of concurrent events at a given time.

---

Update: Someone put a computational geometry flag on this, so I figure I should rephrase this in terms of computational geometry. I have a set of 1-dimensional intervals and I want to calculate how many of those intervals intersect with a given point. Insertion of new intervals must be fast.

Comment: I'm not making this an answer because I'm not familiar with them, but I think you might be able to accomplish this using some form of k-d tree or quad tree - think of a binary tree where levels alternate between being a comparison on start time and end time. Then you could search the tree for the number of nodes overlapping your time. The worst case time would still be O(n), but in the average case if the times are fairly varied would be O(log n).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

- Construction: `O(n log n)`, where `n` is the number of intervals
- Query: `O(m+log n)`, where `m` is the number of query results and `n` is the number of intervals
- Space: `O(n)`

Comment: Are you aware of any database solutions that would implement this as native feature? This is useful with many problems, like reverse lookup country by IP address, geohashing etc..

Comment: @Teemu Ikonen: Not that I know of, but you should talk to a database guy about that.

Comment: @TeemuIkonen: Postgres supports [range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html) natively. There is a containment [operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) `@>` that takes advantage of a GiST or SP-GiST [index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING).

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the other answers, depending on the length of time and the granularity desired, you could simply have an array of counters.  For example, if the length of time is 24 hours and the desired granularity is 1 millisecond, there will be 86,400,000 cells in the array.  With one 4 byte int per cell (which is enough to hold 10^9), that will be less than 700 MB of RAM, versus tree-based solutions which would take at least (8+8+4+4)*10^9 = 24 GB of RAM for two pointers plus two ints per tree node (since 32 bits of addressable memory is insufficient, you'd need 64 bits per pointer).  You can use swap, but this will slow down some queries considerably.

You can also use this solution if you only care about the last 24 hours of data, for example, by using the array as a circular buffer.  Besides the limitation on time and granularity, the other downside is that insertion time of an interval is proportional to the length of the interval, so if interval length is unbounded, you could be in trouble.  Queries, on the other hand, are a single array lookup.

Comment: Interval length is unbounded, but very unlikely to be longer than 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

(Extending the answers by tskuzzy and Snowball)

A balanced binary search tree makes sense, except that the memory requirements would be excessive for your data set.  A [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) would be much more memory efficient, albeit more complicated unless you can use a library.

Keep two trees, one of start times and one of end times.  To insert an event, add the start time to the tree of start times and the end time to the tree of end times.  To query the number of active events at time T, search the the start-time tree to find out how many start times are less than T, and search the end-time tree to find out how many end times are less than T.  Subtract the number of end times from the number of start times, and that's the number of active events.

Insertions and queries should both take O(log N) time.

A few comments:

- The way you have phrased the question, you only care about the *number* of active events, not *which* events were active.  This means you do not need to keep track of which start time goes with which end time! This also makes it easier to avoid the "+M" term in the queries cited by previous answers.
- Be careful about the exact semantics of your query.  In particular, does an event count as active at time T if it starts at time T?  If it ends at time T?  The anwers to these questions affect whether you use < or <= in certain places.
- Do **not** use a "set" data structure, because you almost certainly want to allow and count duplicates.  That is, more than one event might start and/or end at the same time.  A set would typically ignore duplicates.  What you are looking for instead is a "multiset" (sometimes called a "bag").
- Many binary search trees do not support "number of elements < T" queries out of the box.  But it is easy to add this functionality by storing a size at each node.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a sorted set (e.g., a [balanced binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_binary_search_tree) or a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)) data structure with *N* elements. Furthermore, suppose that the sorted set has *O(log N)* search time, *O(log N)* insert time, and *O(N)* space usage (these are reasonable assumptions, see [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree), for example).

One possibility is to have two sorted sets, `bystart` and `byend`, respectively sorted by the start and end times of the events.

To find the number of events that are ongoing at time `t`, ask `byend` for the first interval whose end time is greater than `t`: an *O(log N)* search operation. Call the start time of this interval `left`. Now, ask `bystart` for the number of intervals whose start time is greater than or equal to `left` and less than `t`. This is *O(log N + M)*, where *M* is the number of such intervals. So, the total time for a search is *O(log N + M)*.

Insertion was *O(log N)* for sorted sets, which we have to do once for each sorted set. This makes the total time for the insertion operation *O(log N)*.

Construction of this structure from scratch just consists of *N* insertion operations, so the total time for construction is *O(N log N)*.

Space usage is *O(N)* for each sorted set, so the total space usage is *O(N)*.

Summary:

- Insert: *O(log N)*, where *N* is the number of intervals
- Construct: *O(N log N)*
- Query: *O(log N + M)*, where *M* is the number of results
- Space: *O(N)*

Comment: This is one solution I thought of. I'm not sure if this is better or worse than an interval tree as described by @tskuzzy, but it seems to have the same asymptotic behavior.